# Access denied on Firebase Realtime Database security rules simulator

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

It is hard for me to understand why the simulator puts me off for this input

I supplied this auth token body:

```
{
  "account": "7xms2zm6noz03f2mvn",
  "playerId": "d3221a31-263c-4629-92fb-6cac89b67088"
}
```

I am using custom authentication to supply the above blob.

Please see the attached screenshot for how the simulator treats this:

[image]

[image: firebase response]

This is my database tree:

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that when you use the simulator, the "auth token payload" is actually at the `auth` level, not at the `auth.token` level.

So, you need to simulate the `auth.token.account` claim like this:

```
{
  "token": {
    "account": "7xms2zm6noz03f2mvn",
    "playerId": "d3221a31-263c-4629-92fb-6cac89b67088"
  }
}
```

You can tell it is (apparently) misnamed because if, for example, you select the "Google" provider, then `provider` and `uid` are both at the top level of this blob (which can't be modified), and that is [where you would expect to find them](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database#auth).

Likewise [this image](https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-Kzh7pFq3OnM/Wyk9lGSCmsI/AAAAAAAACMo/EVfmdOfSU5kveWs2_S69w39u3_EC-z6gwCLcBGAs/s1600/pasted%2Bimage%2B0%2B%25287%2529image2.png) from [this blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/06/announcing-firestore-security-rules.html) shows the `token` block as a sub-block in the simulator.